# How can I determine which Android Automotive OS vehicles support apps built using the Android for Cars App Library?

Tags: android, android-automotive

While building an app using the [Android for Cars App Library](http://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps), I noticed that not all of the vehicles running Android Automotive OS with Google-built in are compatible with my app. How can I tell which vehicles can run my app?

I tried looking for a list of vehicles on the [developer.android.com guide](http://d.android.com/training/cars/apps), but didn't see anything there, and I couldn't find anything here on StackOverflow either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Automotive OS vehicles that support Car App Library apps declare a system feature called `android.software.car.templates_host`. You can use the Play Console's Device Catalog to find out which devices have this system feature. For example, [this search](https://play.google.com/console/developers/app/devices?mode=allDevices&systemFeatures=android.software.car.templates_host) (it might take a while to load) will show you all AAOS vehicles with Google built-in that support templated apps. Switch the mode from "All devices" to "Supported devices" to account for any additional dependencies your app has.